# Permanently add persons to a group calendar view

Tags: list-view, calendar, groups, team

I tried out the group calendar feature in SP2010 and it works pretty good. My only problem is that every time I load the page with the calendar view, it only adds my current user in the calendar. So I enter some users or group manually from the "Add Person" text box and it shows exactly what I would like to see by default. The problem is that I did not found any solution to save this in a view or in the default view.

[image]

As my goal is to share the team schedule, I would like be able to set a default list of persons or a group to my calendar view so the user don't have to add all of them manually. I think I am missing something because using a calendar group and displaying only your schedule makes no sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[EDIT] I didn't spot that you were looking for an "official" answer - if you want that I suggest posing the question to Microsoft. One would hope this gets fixed in vNext.

AFAIK this is expected behaviour.

Obviously this is inadequate as (like you say) it effectively defeats the purpose of the Web part.

This has been discussed on numerous forums but the closest item I found to a fix is this:
http://zepeda-mcmillan.blogspot.com/2011/03/displaying-default-resources-on-group.html

The workaround involves using fiddler (a Web debugging proxy) to grab the ECMAScript used to add the appropriate resources to the calendar, uploading the script and referencing it in the appropriate page.

Whilst far from ideal it's a decent blog post and a relatively straightforward solution assuming the resource list wont change too often.

Comment: Thanks a lot. this workaround worked like a charm. This feature is essential and definitely missing from SP2010... I don't get what is the point of having a shared calendar when you can't define a default group of user to be displayed.

Comment: Really glad the fix worked for you :-). Lets hope this gets patched as the feature is very much half baked at present.

Comment: Yes I hope too but all the requests on Connect concerning this request seem to have been deleted. Looks like it is not likely to happen in a SP.

Comment: Old thread I know - but by any chance does anyone know how to remove the default logged in user that always gets added to the top of the list whether or not they are part of the group?

Answer (score 1):

I'm just experimenting with Groupcalendar function, too.
Although I am a big fan of JS/ECMA to pimp SharePoint, I had to find a no code solution, which can be done by End-Users.
It seems to me, that the threatowner was not aware of selector function in the ribbon, neither was I a few minutes ago.
So if you are able to put all persons of your team in one single sharePoint Group (including yourself), you can view every calendar with just one more click.
Just click the downarrow under "people" and select on of the Groups, you are member of.
(Maybe it's neccessary to create a new group but at least its enduser compatible)

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a staff rota and came up with a sort of solution that allows the team to see what they should be doing on any particular day in a sort of Group Calendar.

Basically - stop thinking of a date as a date, but think of it as a piece of text that is ordered by column number that just happens to look like a date.

I created a spreadsheet of dates across the top from column b to ev and then team members a2 to a8. Populated the relevant cells with known activities (luckily a staff rota is usually one activity per date), converted to a Table and then uploaded to SharePoint. I only did 4 months as a full year caused the upload process to crash despite several attempts.

It seems to work in Standard view because SharePoint treats the dates as text, not dates and those dates just happen to be in the right order.

It is possible to select a team member and edit their activities. The difficulty arises when a new team meber needs to be added - then just update the spreadsheet - delete the old SharePoint list and upload the new one. Obvioulsy edit the view to show only the relevant dates displayed by ticking or unticking the appropriate date text box.

Not pretty, but it works.